# Non-vulgar, informal verb for defecate

Tags: synonyms

How can I write about somebody defecating without resorting to childish phrases like 'having a poopoo'.

Is there an equivalent to 'pee' (which can be used by adults to mean urinate) for defecating?

So far I have "taking a dump" but it seems to have a comedic effect in certain cases.

Comment: user2787904, you partly answered your own question. You can use the word *defecate* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/defecate?q=defecate

Answer (score 2):

There are many euphemisms in [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_toilet_slang#Defecation) list, few of which I've heard. I'd probably get the drift if someone used any of them.

I don't see the reason for the specificity. If I am going to excuse myself for such purposes, I might say I'm going to visit the washroom (or little boy's room), and if there was any reason to say so, I might indicate I could be a few minutes-- just so others are not putting their jackets on and lacing up their boots in the expectation of my return within less than sixty seconds. Or perhaps I'd let the Sunday New York Times (City Edition) under my arm say it for me.

If you're going to tell them the nature of the elimination, perhaps you should also include the information that you intend to thoroughly wash your hands in case some fecal matter should contaminate them. Perhaps share information on the consistency and regularity of your bowel movements? I just don't see the need for it.

If you're going for the comedic effect, on the other hand, try using "massive dump".

Answer (score 1):

1) Move one's bowels

2)Do the number two (a bit slangy/ really informal)

Comment: Your second example would normally have *a* instead of *the*.

Comment: Also, I've heard phrase 1 stated as "void one's bowels"

Answer (score 0):

[*Crap*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crap) is both not (that) vulgar and informal. I doubt you can get any better than that:

> crap Vulgar Slang n.
>
> 1. Excrement.
> 2. An act of defecating.
> 3. Foolish, deceitful, or boastful language.
> 4. Cheap or shoddy material.
> 5. Miscellaneous or disorganized items; clutter.
> 6. Insolent talk or behavior.

The equivalent of *taking a dump* would be *having a crap*.

I stress that while *crap* is not all that vulgar, it is not a word you would use in very polite conversation. However, you did ask for informal and it is far less vulgar than *shit*, so I think it fits the bill.

Comment: I never understand why 'crap' is regarded as vulgar. It originates from the name of Thomas Crapper, the Victorian sanitary engineer who invented the modern WC.

Comment: Snopes disagrees. http://www.snopes.com/business/names/crapper.asp

Comment: *Crap* is used in a vulgar/offensive way http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/crap_1?q=crap It's not a word to use normally. In the UK, people say *having a dump*.

Comment: @Tristanr that's why I said not _that_ vulgar and even _stressed_ that it "should not be used in very polite conversation". _Dump_ is already mentioned in the OP. What exactly is the point of your comment?

Comment: My point was that here in the UK, people say *have* rather than *take*, with the word *dump*.

Answer (score 0):

"Go to the bathroom" and "go to the toilet" as euphemisms for "defecate", "take a dump".

"Take a crapper" as an informal equivalent.

"Take a leak" for "urinate".

Comment: Most of these are American English. In the UK, people say *go to the toilet* or just *go to toilet*. The word *the*, is not strictly necessary. The word *take* in this context, is particularly American. In the UK, people usually use the word *have*. Your example with the word *crapper*, should be *crap*. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/crap_1?q=crap

Comment: The word *leak* in this context, is also American.

Answer (score 0):

The term doctors and nurses use when they make inquiry from me is

- How's your bowel movement?
- When was your last bowel movement?
- Have you had your bowels emptied recently?
- Please collect a sliver of your bowel discharge into this little container, and seal the lid with the sticker.

Therefore, to sound pretentiously professional, you would say

- Mom, I am emptying my bowels.
- I need to take care of some movement I am sensing within my bowels.

To be a bit more entertaining,

- There is equivalent of a bucket of unflushed night soil in the toilet bowl. Is it yours?
- I've got bowel plumbing issues. It won't hold too well if you hold me any longer.
- Is that a vowel from your bowel? (aka fart).
- Did I hear vowels from your bowels?